# Apache holding onto requests?

Tags: apache, webserver, weblogic12c

I am using a Linux Apache (Apache/2.2.3 Red Hat) and from time to time we get requests that takes about 5 minutes before it sends the request to the server. I am using Dynatrace to monitor my app and using that I can verify that the request is on the Apache server itself and then gets send to the WebLogic 12 application server. Once on the application server it responds within milliseconds.

This seems to last between 1-3 min and then resolves itself. Every time when this occurs I am using SOAP UI to call the server(s) directly and I cannot seem to find an issue with the application server itself.

I am using the weblogic Apache module (mod_wl_22.so) 
Found the following site ([Weblogic plugin config and troubleshooting](http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=654)) that explains the options very well (apologies for using a link but I cannot copy the whole 2 pages for reference). For the configuration of this plugin and have the following set:

```
KeepAliveEnabled Off
MaxSkipTime 2
ConnectTimeoutSecs 3
```

I cannot see any errors in the errors.log or access.log files as well.

Is there anything else that we can check to debug this plugin a bit more or try and see what is happening during these 5-13 seconds before the request get forwarded to the app server.

Comment: I got the exact same issue. And I got DynaTrace too. But I doubt this being a DNS issue, as technically client TCP connection would be established only after successful DNS resolution?

Comment: were you able to find any other issue with your setup or it's Dynatrace agent to blame on?

Comment: We had several teams running different type of apps. Some of their apps/apache's were not instrumented and still having the same behaviour. So I honestly don't think DT is to blame here. Changing to using IP's instead of server names in the Apache config seem to solve 80% of our issues but we still have the odd times of 5-6 seconds per call.
We are planning to rather implement a Zuul service infrastructure aka something that can be debugged by a developer in case "funnies" occur.

Answer (score 1):

We played with various curls/commands to test round trip to the servers. In the end we ran a test to connect to the servers 40x in a row connecting to the port and just log the start times of these calls. Since this is just connecting and coming back it should be very fast

So we expected to see something like:

```
14:49:49:1 call 1
14:49:49:1 call 2
14:49:49:1 call 3
14:49:49:1 call 4
14:49:49:1 call 5
14:49:49:1 call 6
14:49:49:1 call 7
14:49:49:1 call 8
14:49:49:1 call 9
...
14:49:49:1 call 40
```

While in reality we seen the following

```
14:49:49:1 call 1
14:49:50:5 call 2 --> took more than second
14:49:50:5 call 3
14:49:50:5 call 4
14:49:50:5 call 5
14:49:50:5 call 6
14:49:52:8 call 7 --> took more than 2 seconds
14:49:52:8 call 8
14:49:52:8 call 9
...
14:49:52:8 call 40
```

Every other call took between 1 and 5 seconds. Again nothing error'ly from and application perspective. Seemed like the DNS resolution is a problem. We ran the same test but instead of connecting to myServer:9999 we made use of 123.456.789.123:9999 all instant.